# How can I get element with checked Label in <td> tag?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

In javascipt/jquery How can I get checked element name. These are in table. And I have to reach and detect label of checked checkbox in td tag.

```
$.each(value.Value, function (_, ObjElement) {
                    var tr = $('<tr>').appendTo(table);
                    $("<td>").appendTo(tr);
                    $("<td>", { id: 'clusterList' }).text(ObjElement.Name).append($('<input type=checkbox>').prop("checked", true)).appendTo(tr);

<td id="clusterList">Cluster1<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
<td id="clusterList">Cluster2<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
<td id="clusterList">Cluster3<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
```

result should be like that if first and second checkbox are checked.

Listcluster={Cluster1,Cluster2}

Comment: I can do it with random id. but later?

Comment: Can you can the input checkbox and add a value="cluster1" or it's not possible ?

Comment: I tried but if I write with value, can't be able to see values in interface , am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be *unique*, you should use classes instead. You can store the values in an array using `map` method.

```
var listCluster = $('table td').has('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.textContent || this.innerText;
    // return $.trim( $(this).text() );
}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SUHsT/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td input:checked').parent().text();
```

btw ids must be unique.

Comment: Note OP's example doesn't include a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

1) Ids MUST be Unique. You can not have multiple elements with the same ID.

So with that out of the way, lets assume you have the following DOM:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
   <td id="clusterList1">Cluster1<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
   <td id="clusterList2">Cluster2<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
   <td id="clusterList3">Cluster3<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td></tr></table>
```

And, given that your example does not include name attributes, I am assuming that when you say "name" you mean "the text just before the input field".
Then your jquery would look as follows:

```
     ListCluster = []
     $('table#myTable tr td input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
           if($(this).attr('checked')=='checked'){
              if(ListCluster.indexOf($(this).parent().text()==-1){
                 ListCluster.push($(this).parent().text());
              }
           } else if(ListCluster.indexOf($(this).parent().text()>=-1){
              ListCluster.splice($(this).parent().text(), 1);
           }
      }
```

Here's how it works.

You initialize an array ListCluster. You then add an on change handler to all of the checkboxes at your desired level of nesting. The reason to use a change handler rather then a click handler, is that a change handler will allow you to handle a value change based on spacebar being pressed after tabbing into the checkbox, while a click event would not pick this up.

Inside the change handler, `$(this)` refers to the checkbox changed, while `.parent()` reaches up one level to get its wrapping td.

`.text()` will get a DOMElements text discarding all HTML.

`indexOf()` will return the first index where a value is found or -1 if it is never found thus comparing indexOf to -1 is equivalent to asking "is this item present?"

`.push()` is a function which adds an element to the end of an array, while `.splice(x, y)` will remove y elements starting at the index of x.